# 'next' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++

I am trying to use `std::next()` to get the next element in a `std::vector`. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main(){
    std::vector<double> Vec1(3,0.0);
    Vec1.at(0) = 55.0; Vec1.at(1) = -3.25; Vec1.at(2) = 528.22;

    for ( std::vector<double>::iterator i = Vec1.begin(); i != Vec1.end(); ++i){
        std::vector<double>::iterator nx = std::next(i,2);
        std::cout << "The current index is " << i-Vec1.begin() << " and the current element at this index is " << *i << " and the next element is " << *nx << std::endl;
    }
}
```

When I do this, my compiler complains with the following error:

> error: 'next' is not a member of 'std'

Does anyone know why this error is happening? I looked [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/next/) and they use the same syntax (`std::next`).

Comment: which compiler/version? C++11 support enabled?

Comment: I am on windows 10 and using VS Code and to be totally honest I have no idea, which seems ridiculous saying outloud. Let me see if I can find out.

Comment: Note that your code has a terrible bug. You iterate `i` through the whole vector but `std::next(i, 2)` is **two elements beyond** `i`. You'll try to print elements past the end of the vector...

Comment: Thank you - I was actually aware of that. I just wanted to experiment with what I could and could not do with iterators. I was trying to see if it would let me go outside the array bounds. First I need to get `next` working though

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Using IDE or command line? Please provide name and version of IDE or compiler, whatever you are using.

Comment: Reading past the end of a container is undefined behavior so it might do anything including appearing to work. If you're lucky it will quickly and loudly crash to alert you to the problem.

Comment: `std::next()` was introduced in C++11.   If your compiler or library predate C++11, or are configured to use a pre-C++11 dialect (which several compilers are, even if they are more recent than 2011) then `std::next()` will not be recognised.

Comment: I am using VSCode version 1.43.2. I have the following extensions installed: C/C++, C/C++ Compile Run, and C++ Intellisense

Comment: vscode is not a compiler, but rather uses some other installed compiler. That compiler will probably have an option to enable c++11 stuff. It may be different for different compilers. vscode will have a way to pass build flags.

Comment: That's just the version of the ide, you must have installed a compiler somewhere, which one and what version

Comment: in the example you refer to they use foreach but that is not what you are using...

Comment: @HansPassant Thats not his problem. `std::vector` doesn't need to know anything about `std::next`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're unsure what compiler is installed. As the comments have mentioned, you need to be using a compiler that supports c++11 in order to use [std::next](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

You can get the Microsoft Visual Studio (MSVC) Community edition [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). This is a fully integrated development editor (IDE) that uses Microsofts c++ compiler. Its a self-contained product that will enable you to do what you're expecting to be able to do.

Now, if you like vscode more or use it for other langauges (its great for web languages too!), you can configure vscode to work with Visual Studio too. There is a great instruction set [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc).

That being said, you can also use Visual Studio with any other IDE and most of them make it easy to use MSVC's compiler.

This is how I personally develop on Windows, a combination of [CMake](https://cmake.org/overview/), [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) (or if you want tmux as I do, [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) (which also has other compilers availble if desired) ), and [Vim](https://www.vim.org/about.php)

this all starts by having a modern compiler installed. MSVC Community edition enables everything and more than what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes - you're correct. I'm lost at how to tell which version it is using. I've installed some in the past and I can't keep them straight. If I go to C/C++ Compile Run extension it says the compiler is g++. I will try to follow the instructions at the link you provided, hopefully I can get it sorted out.

Comment: @Nukesub why don't just look at [config files in VS code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) to see the path to the compiler? Open c_cpp_properties.json or tasks.json and the exe file should be there